# How do I update the JavaScript this-pointer inside an object to point to another object?

Tags: javascript, this, method-call

I'm having some trouble with JavaScript and the passing of a function as parameter of another function.

let's say we are inside a class and do something like that:

```
this.get('target').update(this.onSuccess, this.onFail);
```

- 'target' is a JavaScript-object that has a method called update()
- I'm calling this method and pass tow methods of the caller-class along as parameters

inside that update-method some stuff happens and when it's done that method should either call the onSuccess-method or the onFail-method. this looks something like:

```
update: function(onSuccess, onFail) {
  if(true) {
    onSuccess();
  } else {
    onFail();
  }
}
```

until now, everything works pretty fine! but inside those success/fail-methods, that are defined in the caller-class (the one that calls above update-method), I'm using a this-pointer:

```
onFail: function() {
  alert('Error: ' + this.get('target').error);  
}
```

that this-pointer causes some issues. it doesn't point to the class where the method initially was defined but to the 'target'-object.

what I need to do now is to update the this-pointer right before the onSuccess / onFail calls inside the 'target'-class to make the methods work again. but this doesn't work due to a 'invalid assignment left-hand side'-error.

what is the best practice for a scenario like that? any ideas? thx in advance!!!

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function that "binds" a function to a certain object (using a closure) and than pass these bound functions to the handler:

```
function bind(obj, fun) {
   return function() {
      return fun.apply(obj, arguments);
   };
};

update(bind(this, this.onSuccess), bind(this, this.onFail));
```

Comment: thx, that solved my problem! I forgot to mention that I can't make any bigger changes inside the caller-class! so I only pass the 'this-pointer' along and to the binding-stuff inside the target-class. that works perfectly fine!!

Answer (score 4):

You have two options when calling `update()`:

- javascript function `call()`
- javascript function `apply()`

the main difference being how you pass parameters to it. But they both allow scope/context injection.

Your code should look something like this:

```
this.get('target').update.call(this, this.onSuccess, this.onFail);
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect this, you need a `bind()` (or similar) method in the `Function` class, as found in almost all JavaScript libraries:

```
if(!Function.prototype.bind){
    Function.prototype.bind = function(scope) {
      var _function = this;

      return function() {
        return _function.apply(scope, arguments);
      }
    }
}
```

Now do something like this:

```
update: function(onSuccess, onFail) {
  if(true) {
    onSuccess.bind(this)();
  } else {
    onFail.bind(this)();
  }
}
```

The mechanism is explained here: [Binding Scope in JavaScript](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/04/28/binding-scope-in-javascript/)